# Setting On Change on id from parameter does not work

Tags: jquery, forms, sharepoint, element, onchange

I am using SharePoint 2013, but this is more of a jQuery question/issue.
In SharePoint, the form elements are given ID's based off of the name and a key of some sort.

I am able to get the ID for the form element that I am trying to add a "on change" function to.

```
var idEventDate = $('nobr:contains("Event Date")').closest('tr').find('input[title$="Event Date"]').prop('id');
```

I used an alert to make sure I get the value.

When I take that value and create an "on change" listener, nothing happens.  There aren't any errors either.

In the code below, I am doing an insert into a div and then I am trying to add the "on change" function to the Event Date field element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push( "sharePointReady" );

function sharePointReady() {
    // Adding a Title as a quick way to determine which screen I am on
    $('nobr:contains("Title")').closest('table').before('<div id="customHeader"><h1>Create a New Memo</h1></div>');

    var idEventDate = $('nobr:contains("Event Date")').closest('tr').find('input[title$="Event Date"]').prop('id');

    $(document).on("change","#" + idEventDate, function(){
        alert("changed");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it wasn't necessary to get the ID, since I had found the element.

```
$('nobr:contains("Event Date")').closest('tr').find('input[title$="Event Date"]').on("change",  function(){
        alert("changed");
    });
```

However, I still wished that getting the ID as a string would work.  But, for now, it was just an extra unneeded step.